# GLSL C++ glVertexAttribPointer & glDrawElements return GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, glsl

I get the error `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` in lines: 164 & 183 and I don't know how to fix it.

*line 164*:

```
GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0));
```

*line 183:*

```
GLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6 ,GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr));
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.3.0-devel - padoka PPA.
By the way I want to draw a Cube.

main:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>   
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define ASSERT(x) if (!(x)) std::cin.get();
#define GLCall(x) GLClearError();\
    x;\
    ASSERT(GLLogCall(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__))

static void GLClearError()
{
    while(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR);
}

static bool GLLogCall(const char* function, const char* file, int line)
{
    while(GLenum error = glGetError())
    {
        std::cout << "[OPENGL ERROR](" <<  error << ")" << function <<
        " " << file << " line: " << line << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

struct ShaderProgramSource
{
    std::string VertexSource;
    std::string FragmentSource;
};

static ShaderProgramSource ParseShader(const std::string& filepath)
{
    std::fstream stream (filepath);

    enum ShaderType
    {
        NONE = -1, VERTEX = 0, FRAGMENT = 1
    };

    std::string _line;
    std::stringstream ss[2];
    ShaderType type = ShaderType::NONE;

    while(getline(stream, _line))
    {
        if(_line.find("#shader") != std::string::npos)
        {
            if(_line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos)
                type = ShaderType::VERTEX;
            else if (_line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos)
                type = ShaderType::FRAGMENT;
        }
        else
        {
            ss[(int)type] << _line << '\n';
        }
    }

    return { ss[0].str(), ss[1].str() };
}

static unsigned CompileShader(unsigned type, const std::string& source)
{
    std::cout << "Compile Shader \n";

    unsigned id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    // TODO: ERROR handling

    int result;

    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if(!result)
    {
        int lenght;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &lenght);
        char* message = (char*)&source[0];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, lenght, &lenght, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << " " << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
    unsigned program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library*/
    if(!glfwInit())
        return -1;


    GLCall(glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4));
    GLCall(glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3));
    GLCall(glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE));
    GLCall(glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE));

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGl context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

    if(!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }


    /* Make the window's context current */
    GLCall(glfwMakeContextCurrent(window));

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;


    float positions[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,   //0
         0.5f, -0.5f,   //1
         0.5f,  0.5f,   //2
        -0.5f,  0.5f   //3
    };

    unsigned indices[]
    {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };

    unsigned buffer;
    GLCall(glGenBuffers(1, &buffer));
    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer));
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*2*sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW));

    GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(0));
    GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0));

    unsigned ibo;   //index buffer Object
    GLCall(glGenBuffers(1, &ibo));
    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo));
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW));

    //TODO: Relative path
    ShaderProgramSource source = ParseShader("Path"); //This path leads to Shaders

    unsigned shader = CreateShader(source.VertexSource, source.FragmentSource);
    GLCall(glUseProgram(shader));

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        GLCall(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT));

        GLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6 ,GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr));

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        GLCall(glfwSwapBuffers(window));

        /* Poll for and process events */
        GLCall(glfwPollEvents());
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Shader:

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position; 

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = position; 
};

#shader fragment
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color; 

void main() 
{
    color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call any OpenGL instructions, before you have a current and valid [OpenGL context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context).
Further, `glfwWindowHint` and `glfwMakeContextCurrent` are no OpenGL instructions.

So the `glError` checks by the macro `GLCall`, like

```
GLCall(glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4));
....
```

and

```
GLCall(glfwMakeContextCurrent(window));
```

are invalid and doesn't make any sense.

The first valid use of the macro `GLCall` would be after `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)`.

---

Since you are using a core profile context, with forward compatibility:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

you have to create an bind a named [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).
Note, in a core profile context the default vertex array object (0) is not valid.

It is sufficient to create and bind one named vertex array object, before you create the buffer objects and define the array of generic vertex attribute data. This object takes place of the default vertex array object in compatibility profile:

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
glBindVertexArray( vao );

unsigned buffer;
GLCall(glGenBuffers(1, &buffer));
GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer));
GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*2*sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW));

GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(0));
GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0));

unsigned ibo;   //index buffer Object
GLCall(glGenBuffers(1, &ibo));
GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo));
GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW));
```

---

Set `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE`, before initializing GLEW.

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
```

See the [GLEW documantation](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) which says:

> GLEW obtains information on the supported extensions from the graphics driver. Experimental or pre-release drivers, however, might not report every available extension through the standard mechanism, in which case GLEW will report it unsupported. To circumvent this situation, the `glewExperimental` global switch can be turned on by setting it to `GL_TRUE` before calling `glewInit()`, which ensures that all extensions with valid entry points will be exposed.

Comment: Wow Thank you It works right now. Yeah I am pretty new at glsl xD.